# localhost3000/1/index.html が開けません

Tags: windows

http://ftpkimi-hirama.udr.weblife.me が私のHPのアドレスですが、たどり着けません。このアドレスは存在するのですが、二重にアドレスが使用されているかも知れません。

Comment: タイトルに書かれた`localhost`は一般的に自分自身のPCを指すホスト名です。一方で本文中の`weblife.me`はレンタルサーバのようなので、「自分で立てたサーバに対して」なのか「外部のサーバに対して」なのか質問がはっきりしません。また、「このアドレスは存在する」「二重にアドレスが使用されているかも」と判断された材料はなんでしょうか。万一同じアドレスが他人に使われているのだとしたら、接続できないではなく「他人のコンテンツが表示される」などにならないでしょうか。単に「できません」だけでなく、何か表示されたエラーメッセージ等も含めてもらえると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: 回答を読まず一方的に語るのみのようです。それは質問とは言いません。

Answer (score 2):

タイトルと本文でURLが異なります。とりあず本文側のURLは間違っているため、IPアドレス以前の問題です。まずはURLを再度確認すべきです。

Comment: 同一サーバーで、HP制作ソフトはグレードアップしたモノを使っています。グレードアップする前のｈｐのアドレス上に、新しいｈｐを構築するのは、無理があるでしょうか。

Comment: @平間公郎 年が明けるのを待ってサポートセンターに問い合わせましょう...
 http://www.digitalstage.jp/support/archives/2017/11/1129.php

Answer (score 0):

問題の起きている環境がはっきりしないので、現時点で気になる点を挙げてみると

**1点目**
単純に打ち間違いかもしれませんが、タイトルの`localhost3000`は正しくは`localhost:3000`ではないでしょうか。

**2点目**
本文の`http://ftpkimi-hirama.udr.weblife.me/`ですが、`ftp`という文字が含まれていることを考えるとレンタルサーバ等へのコンテンツアップロード用のURLと、実際にHP(webサイト)としてアクセスする際のURLは別のものになるのではないでしょうか。